# The group with its operation given recursively

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to prove the group properties of the following function $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ given recursively

1. $f(x,0)=0$
2. $f(0,y)=y$
3. $f(x+1,y+1)=\min(\mathbb{N}-(\{f(i,y+1):i\leq x\}\cup\{f(x+1,j):j\leq y\}))$

Intuitively, an element $a_{i,j}$ of the multiplication table of $f$ is just the minimal element that doesn't appear among the elements on the left and top. Here's the fragment:

[image]

It follows from the definition that $0$ has to be the identity. I've also proved by induction the property $x^2=0$ holds. So if it's indeed a group it has to be boolean. The problem, as it's always, with the associativity.  The induction seems to be not so trivial here. May be you know what group (if it is...) we have here?

Comment: This is called "nimber addition." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber

Comment: @TheEmptyFunction Oh, thank's a lot!

Comment: Appears to have closed subsets of order $2^n$ for $n\in\Bbb N_0$, if it's a group they must be normal subgrous. What happens when you factor out a subgroup?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts interesting, trying to think...

Comment: Isn't addition like in the algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_2$?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts thanks a lot!